# How do I use spaces in my command to cd to a directory and its sub directories using aliases?

Tags: shell, unix, alias, tcsh

Suppose I am interested in this directory :

/home/username/dummy1/

And dummy1 has these subfolders :

sub_dummy1

sub_dummy2
..
which in turn can consist of various directories and so on.

Is there anyway I can write an alias in .cshrc to navigate to dummy1 and various subfolders ?

For e.g :

```
username@unix-system: dummy1 sub_dummy1
username@unix-system: dummy1 sub_dummy1/sub_sub_dummy1/sub_sub_sub_dummy2
```

(Takes me to sub_dummy1 if I hit Enter, shows me contents of sub_dummy1 if I hit Tab)

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for a question that's more about achieving a desired interactive shell usage mode than software development as such.

Comment: (On any of the more modern shells I'm familiar with one can write custom autocompletion functions that generate the set of results shown if one hits tab, but csh is... well... csh; writing software with or for it is [generally considered a mistake](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

try alias

```
alias mycmd="cd ${HOME}/dummy1/sub_dummy1 && ls -1"
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for : You can't hit 'Tab' to further navigate sub directories and so on. Your command just goes to sub_dummy1 and lists contents..